# Is there any function to turn a date from 1-1-2018 to 2018-1-1

Tags: r

If I have a date written in this format (element is a string):

```
c("10-1-2018")
```

Is there any command I can use to turn it into this format instead?

```
c("2018-10-1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as.Date` to convert it to a `Date` object which will print in the format you want.

```
as.Date(c("10-1-2018"), format = '%m-%d-%Y')
```

If you actually want it as character, just use `as.character`.

```
as.character(as.Date(c("10-1-2018"), format = '%m-%d-%Y'))
```